# hazelcast docker container can't run continuously

Tags: docker, hazelcast

I build a hazelcast docker container.But when I run hazelcast container,it only prints some starting logs without really running.
The Dockerfile is:

```
#centos7_jdk7 is a centos7 operating system installing jdk7
FROM tianshangdeyun/centos7_jdk7
#hazelcast-3.6.1 is download from hazelcast offical site
COPY hazelcast-3.6.1 /hazelcast-3.6.1
#add start hazelcast script
COPY run.sh /run.sh
RUN chmod 777 /run.sh
expose 5701
CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

The run.sh is:

```
#!/bin/bash
/hazelcast-3.6.1/bin/server.sh
```

I run the hazelcast container with 'docker run hazelcast:3.6.1'.
The log is prints is:
[image]
But 'docker ps' can't see the process.
Wish your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `server.sh` starts the java application that does not run in foreground. This means that server.sh starts the server, exit itself, so your run.sh script also exit, and docker thinks the work is done and exit, even though hazelcast is still running. This is a common problem when dockerizing some application.

As far as I can tell, I don't see a native way to run hazelcast in foreground. What you can do then is modify server.sh. In this case, the modification is very easy, all you have to do is to add a **wait** 
statement in `server.sh`, towards the end, after the `echo $! > ${PID_FILE}`

```
if [ -z "${PID}" ]; then
    echo "Process id for hazelcast instance is written to location: {$PID_FILE}"
    $RUN_JAVA -server $JAVA_OPTS com.hazelcast.core.server.StartServer &
    echo $! > ${PID_FILE}
    wait
else
    echo "Another hazelcast instance is already started in this folder. To start a new instance, please unzip 3.6.1.zip/tar.gz in a new folder."
    exit 0
fi
```

The wait statement will wait until the java application is terminated, and then return, so your run.sh will return, and your docker container will exit.
Try that, it will work!

Comment: Starting scripts shipped with an application (`server.sh` in this case) change frequently with newer version. My answer might not work with version other than 3.6.1